# I have a python script which lists files with specific extensions. I want to print the file names of those files into a txt file. All in the same path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this path *C:\Users\PacY\Documents* it contains files and folders. I have a python script which can print out files with extension *pdf*, *docx*, *jpg*. I want to add file names of those files with those extensions fore mentioned, into a txt file called "extension_files" located in the same path *C:\Users\PacY\Documents*.

The code is below.

```
import os
path = r'C:\Users\PacY\Documents'

extensions = ['.pdf', '.docx', '.jpg']


for file in os.listdir(path):
    for extension in extensions:
        if file.__contains__(extension):
            print(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
import os

path = r'C:\Users\PacY\Documents'

extensions = ['.pdf', '.docx', '.jpg']

txt_file = r"C:\Users\PacY\Documents\found_files\txt.txt"  # name of your txt file

with open(txt_file, "a+") as txt:
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        for extension in extensions:
            if file.__contains__(extension):
                txt.write(file)
                txt.write("\n")
```

Comment: thank you. but the txt file where the files should be copied to "extension_files" is getting all files names of files in the path *C:\Users\PacY\Documents*. I should expect only *pdf*, *docx*,*jpg* files only. Thanks

Comment: sorry @Vova it has worked. I didn't mention the txt file before.

Comment: Yeah,  it appends the data, not create the new.
Please, set it done, and press up button if it helped you. Thanks

Comment: if you spare one minute to answer this. what if I have to save those files to a folder named "found_files" . any additional code to copy those files to that folder. thanks

Comment: @Y Pac just set your path to the txt_file with filename.txt

For example:

`txt_file = r"C:\Users\proje\Documents\txt.txt"`

Comment: I have done it Thanks. If I am to copy those files to a folder called "found_files" what should I add.

Comment: @YPac what the full path?

Comment: *C:\Users\PacY\Documents\found_files*

Comment: `txt_file = r"C:\Users\PacY\Documents\found_files\txt.txt"`

Comment: May you please edit it in the above code. So that I may be able to see it clearly. Thanks

Comment: @YPac For the future you need to set the full path with extension of file